# Button button = findViewById(R.id.button) always resolves to null in Android

Tags: android

I'm new to Android development, so pardon my ignorance.

`findViewById` of a button I added always resolves to `null`. Hence if I try to `setonClickListener` it fails the whole Activity.

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

        Button buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onButtonClick((Button) view);
            }

        });

    }

    public void onButtonClick(Button view) {
        TextView textHello = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textHello.setText("Clicked !!!");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.pluralsight.activitylifecycle.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.pluralsight.activitylifecycle.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/buttonClick"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="54dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323531/tabhost-setup-gives-null-pointer-exception-android-studio/21324579#21324579

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is because `findViewById()` searches in the `activity_main` layout, while the button is located in the fragment's layout `fragment_main`.

Move that piece of code in the `onCreateView()` method of the fragment:

```
//...

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
Button buttonClick = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        onButtonClick((Button) view);
    }
});
```

Notice that now you access it through `rootView` view:

```
Button buttonClick = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

otherwise you would get again NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

The button code should be moved to the `PlaceholderFragment()` class. There you will call the layout `fragment_main.xml` in the `onCreateView` method. Like so

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    Button buttonClick = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onButtonClick((Button) view);
        }

    });

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`R.id.button` is not part of `R.layout.activity_main`. How should the activity find it in the content view?

The layout that contains the button is displayed by the Fragment, so you have to get the Button there, in the Fragment.