# Unfortunately <project name> has stopped message

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm new to android and I'm using Android studio.I have created a basic program with two buttons.But once I started the emulator the app doesn't start.I'm getting a message saying 'Unfortunately -project name- has stopped'. But the code compiled without any error.Here I'm attaching the codes.

AndroidMAnifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.projectdrogo" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.projectdrogo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my MainActivity.java code

```
package com.example.projectdrogo;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    int counter;
    Button add,subtract;
    TextView textview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        counter =0;
        add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        subtract=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bSubtract);
        textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                counter++;
                textview.setText("Your Total is "+counter);
            }
        });
        subtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                counter--;
                textview.setText("Your Total is "+counter);
            }
        });

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.projectdrogo.MainActivity" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.projectdrogo.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.projectdrogo.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/name"
            android:textSize="50dp"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />


        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Subtract One"
            android:id="@+id/bSubtract"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add One"
            android:id="@+id/bAdd"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me.I'm stuck in this.
Thank you

Comment: Is there a stack trace from the LogCat?

Comment: How can I find the LogCat in Android studio?Thanks

Comment: If you can specify the errors in your log cat field it will use much more easy to find the problem...

Comment: @user3230212 Do you have a fragment by the name `PlaceholderFragment.java`

Comment: @Raghunandan he taken it as a inner class in Activity

Comment: Please wait and I'll post it.

Comment: Can't post the error log.It's too long and stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post it.

Comment: I don't know why but there are more than 10 duplicates of this on Stackoverflow. One is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323531/tabhost-setup-gives-null-pointer-exception-android-studio/21324579#21324579

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`activity_main.xml` does not have a button or textviews. Looks like its in a Fragment Layout

I guess you have a fragment

```
PlaceholderFragment newFragment = new  PlaceholderFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Then in onCreateView of Fragment

```
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
 add = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
 subtract=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.bSubtract);
 textview=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.name);
 ...// rest of the code
```

You have a `FrameLayout` which is a container. You need to add the fragment to the container. Also the views in activity belong to fragment layout. So you need to initialize the same in onCreateView as suggested.

Edit:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    PlaceholderFragment newFragment = new  PlaceholderFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.container, newFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Then

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

```
    int counter;
    Button add,subtract;
    TextView textview;
    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);   
        add = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        subtract=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.bSubtract);
        textview=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        ... // rest of the code

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry.I can't understand this.Please help.Thanks

Comment: @user3230212 what is that you don't understand

Comment: @user3230212 posted edit the rest is for you to figure out and specify what you don't understand

Comment: What am I suppose to do now?Do I need to add this code to my code?

Comment: @user3230212 you are supposed to look to the edit and make the changes in your code accordingly. The code posted is clear enough.

Comment: I've changed the code.But Now I get errors.
error: cannot find symbol class FragmentTransaction
error: cannot find symbol variable name

Comment: @user3230212 you need few import statements. I can't post everything. that is obvious and the ide should you import the right ones. shift+ctrl+0 in eclipse

Comment: Thank you very much.It worked.Sorry for the inconvenience caused by me.